# Running a ps1 through a VBS in background

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I'm trying to run a ps1 script that makes a "beep" alert when you lock or unlock your session on windows xp. I already got it and I'm trying to call that script through a VBS script. Problem is that if I execute the VBS manually, the power shell window appears and obviously, when i closed it, the script stop running. Here's my code:

This is the ps1:

$sysevent = [microsoft.win32.systemevents]

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $sysevent -EventName SessionSwitch -Action {[console]::Beep();Write-host ($args[1]).Reason}

And this is the VBS:

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") objShell.Run("powershell.exe -noexit c:\beep.ps1")

Does anybody know how to prevent the power shell window and running the script in the background?

Comment: Did you know that there is a windows system call to make a beep?  because there is.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx  Might help to simplify your approach.

Comment: @Wug and how would you make that call from vbscript ?

Comment: @peter you could write like a 6 liner com wrapper for it.  You can do com calls from vba

Comment: writing com objects is something most vbscript programmers are not capable of, also it's not vba but vbs but you could use a com omject there too and last you have to register that com on every machine you are going to use that script what makes it difficult to roll out

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a ps1 script, i use this one liner

```
WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell").Run "cmd /c " & chr(7),0,False
```

Also found some usefull suggestions at http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=11616563 like the little c program that you can compile or the nircmd command.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question about hiding the PS window, you can add the zero switch to the Run method to hide the window:

```
objShell.Run "powershell.exe -noexit c:\beep.ps1" , 0, False
```

https://www.vbsedit.com/html/6f28899c-d653-4555-8a59-49640b0e32ea.asp